# Redirect pages to fix crawl errors

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect, crawl-errors

Google is giving me a crawl error for pages that I have removed like `www.mysite.com/mypage.html`. I want to redirect this pages to the new page `www.mysite.com/mysite/mypage`. 
I tried to do that by using *.htaccess* but instead of fixing the problem, the crawl pages increased and a new crawl came `www.mysite.com/www.mysite.com`.

This is my *.htaccess* file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sitename/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /sitename/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Should I add this after the rewrite rule or I should do something else?

```
RewriteRule ^pagename\.html$ http://www.sitename.com/pagename [R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be to do with that rewritebase command.

Have you checked you redirects to see if they work properly?

I would place my custom redirects above the rewrite block of code. It makes more sense and avoids that rewritebase causing trouble. Just make sure you have a rewriteengine on before it all.

Comment: i tried it but under the rewrite code i will try to add it above it but i am afraid that the website may crash but you mean above all the rewrite rolls even the RewriteEngine On

Comment: i tried it before and after RewriteEngine On but nothing happened

Comment: RewriteEngine On should always be first. I was talking about the rewritebase command and it's effect on anything after it

Comment: The location of the `RewriteBase` directive makes no difference (it's not strictly processed top to bottom). The _last_ `RewriteBase` directive (if there is more than one) controls the entire file, regardless of where it is placed. (The same as with the `RewriteEngine` directive for that matter.) However, the `RewriteBase` directive is not the issue in the code that the OP posted - its not actually being used, since there are no relative path substitutions in the OPs code.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the `Redirect` command in `.htaccess` rather than a rewrite rule for simple redirects:

```
redirect 301 /pagename.html http://www.sitename.com/pagename
```

But if you would rather use a rewrite rule, your rule looks like it should be fine.

When I run WordPress, it is more convenient for me to install the [Quick Page/Post Redirect Plugin](http://www.fischercreativemedia.com/wordpress-plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/) that allows me to specify all the redirects from the WordPress admin interface.  I also install the [True Google 404 Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/trueGoogle404) that keeps track of 404s in the admin interface so I know which redirects to add.

Comment: thanks Stephen Ostermiller for replay i installed the plugin Quick Page/Post Redirect Plugin and redirected a page and opened the page to see if i is redirected or no but it still gives me 401 not found

Comment: Not found is 404, 401 is "not authorized".  There is something else going on.

Comment: what do you mean by something else ?? this is what appears    Not Found
The requested URL /servers.html was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
Dimofinf Hosting mod_fcgid/2.3.6 Server at www.digitalways.com.sa Port 80

Comment: You had said "401" not "404".  Based on the ErrorDocument error message you just pasted in, you also have a problem similar to this one: http://serverfault.com/questions/299731/error-when-creating-a-custom-errordocument-404-in-apache